# How to vectorize Pandas statement with matrices

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization, sparse-matrix

I have the following statement in Pandas that uses the `apply` method which can take up to 2 minutes long.

I read that in order to optimize the speed. I should vectorize the statement. My original statement looks like this:

```
output_data["on_s"] = output_data["m_ind"].apply(lambda x: my_matrix[x, 0] + my_matrix[x, 1] + my_matrix[x, 2]
```

Where `my_matrix` is spicy.sparse matrix. So my initial step was to use the `sum` method:

```
summed_matrix = my_matrix.sum(axis=1)
```

But then after this point I get stuck on how to proceed.

Update: Including example data

The matrice looks like this (scipy.sparse.csr_matrix):

```
(290730, 2)     0.3058016922838267
(290731, 2)     0.3390328430763723
(290733, 2)     0.0838999800585995
(290734, 2)     0.0237008960604337
(290735, 2)     0.0116864263235209
```

`output_data["m_ind"]` is just a Pandas series that has come values like so:

```
97543
97544
97545
97546
97547
```

Comment: Please share a sample of `output_data` and `my_matrix`. Always provide a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  when asking for help, so people can understand clearly what you want and reproduce your problem. This should be useful: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @Rodalm added data!

Answer (score 1):

**An Update: You have convert sparse matrix into dense matrix first**

Since you haven't provided any reproducible code I can't understand what is your problem exactly and give you an very very precise answer. But I will answer according to my understanding.
Let's assume your `my_matrix` is some thing like this

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9]]
```

then the `summed_matrix` will be like `[6,15,24]`. So if my assumption is right it looks like you are almost there.

First I'll give you the simplest answer.
Try using this line.

```
output_data["on_s"] = output_data["m_ind"].apply(lambda x: summed_matrix[x])
```

Then we can try this completely vectorized method.

> 1. Turn `m_ind` into a one hot encoded array `ohe_array`. Be careful to generate `ohe_array` according to the increasing order (sorted).
>    Otherwise you will get the wrong answer. refer [this](https://stackabuse.com/one-hot-encoding-in-python-with-pandas-and-scikit-learn/)
> 2. Then get the **dot product** of `ohe_array` and `summed_matrix`. refer  [this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)
> 3. Assign the result into the column `on_s`

Also We can try the following code and compare performance against `apply`.

```
indexes = output_data["m_ind"].values
on_s = []
for i in indexes:
    on_s.append(summed_matrix[i])

output_data['on-s'] = on_s
```